# Monitor passenger-status on Nagios using bash script

Tags: bash, passenger, nagios

I wanted to monitor our rails application via PASSENGER-STATUS using Nagios but i can't find a plugin that is suitable for the current version of our passenger.

I wanted to watch the "Requests in queue" since i always have a 0 Requests in top-level queue even if i have hundreds of Requests in queue in all our application.

```
.---------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

.---------- Application groups -----------
/webapps/example.local#default:
  App root: /webapps/example.local
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 16915   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 9M      Last used: 2s ago
```

Im using the ff version:

```
Passenger (4.0.2)
Nagios 3.5.1
```

I created a bash script that will grep the Requests in queue.

```
#!/bin/bash

queue=`passenger-status | grep -A 1 "myapp1" | grep "Requests in queue:" | awk '{print $4}'`

if [ $queue == 0 ]
    then
        echo "OK - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 0
  elif [ $queue -le 10 ]
    then
        echo "Warning - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 1
  elif [ $queue > 10 ]
    then
        echo "Critical - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 2
  else
        echo "Unknown Error - Please check config."
        exit 3
fi
```

When I run the script manually. Im getting the right result.

```
[root@localhost user]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_passenger_queue.sh
OK - 0 Passenger Queue on myapp1
```

But when I run the script using the NRPE plugin. It gives me different result.

```
[root@localhost user]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_passenger_queue
Unknown Error -  Please check config.
```

I tried to run the NRPE plugin on my Nagios Server and I got the same result.

```
[root@nagios user]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c check_passenger_queue
Unknown Error -  Please check config.
```

Comment: A simple bash script would do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jim. Right now, i trying to create a bash script and I manage to grep the Requests in queue and do a if statement to determine if OK, WARNING, CRITICAL or Unknown. But when I tried to use it using NRPE, it fails. I edited my post above to include my script and the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the nrpe.cfg line and the nagios comands.cfg entries for this?

Comment: Hi Jim, I think its a user problem since NRPE service is using NRPE user and passenger-status under rvm is ran by root by default. I tried to edit my /etc/sudoers but im still having problem. And I just came up with this solution. I create a new .sh and run my passenger-status via cron under root and save the result to a file and configure my check_passenger_queue.sh to just look at the file. Thank you very much again Jim.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

1. I created a bash script that will command passenger-status and save it to text file.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myapp1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

rvmsudo /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/passenger-status > /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/passenger/passenger-status.txt
```

2. I created a nagios plugin that will look for Requests in queue of a certain app.

```
#!/bin/bash

queue=`cat /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/passenger/passenger-status.txt | grep -A 1 "myapp1" | grep "Requests in queue:" | awk '{print $4}'`

if [ $queue -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "OK - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 0
  elif [ $queue -le 10 ]; then
        echo "Warning - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 1
  elif [ $queue -ge 11 ]; then
        echo "Critical - $queue Passenger Queue on myapp1"
        exit 2
  else
        echo "Unknown Error - $queue Please check config."
        exit 3
fi
```

3. Edit nrpe config to add my plugin.

```
vi /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
command[check_passenger_queue]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_passenger_queue.sh
```

4. Check my nagios plugin if working.

/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_passenger_queue

Answer (score 0):

`passenger-status` needs to be run with `rvmsudo` as indicated by Eman. NRPE is invoked with user *nagios* and as you are calling `passenger-status` without `rvmsudo` you most likely get your *unkown error*.

On the other hand when you call your plugin with user *nagios* over NRPE using `rvmsudo passenger-status` a password is requested when your script hits `rvmsudo`. This won't help eather as you cannot enter a password when calling a plugin over NRPE.

So one solution documented in nrpe.cfg is

1. uncomment `command_prefix=/usr/bin/sudo` in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
2. add user *nagios* to /etc/sudoers with `nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/,/path/to/passenger-status`. IMPORTANT: Make sure you edit /etc/sudoers with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`!
3. restart nagios-nrpe-server with `sudo service nagios-nrpe-server restart`

Step 2. assumes that your plugin is in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins.

The path to `passenger-status` can be identified with `rvmsudo which passenger-status`. Also make sure that `rvmsudo` is in you PATH.